# C++,boost/asio. Не могу получить и отправить сообщение клиенту

Tags: c++, асинхронность, boost, сетевое-программирование, boost.asio

пишу простое клиент-серверное приложение, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу отправить данные клиенту и получить данные от клиента, пробовал добавить mutex, думал что 2 потока используют один и тот же сокет из-за этого и проблема, но не помогло (возможно я не правильно его использовал), потом думал, что проблема в методе io_service.run(), по перемещал его по коду, но тоже не помогло. Сейчас предоставлю код.
Что можно улучшить в коде, можете указать на мои ошибки и недочеты?
**Буду рад любой справедливой критике!**

**Сервер
Server.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <locale>
#include <mutex>

#include "utillity.hpp"

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601

#endif


using namespace boost::asio;
using socket_ptr = boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::socket>;


class Server : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Server> {
private:
    io_service&             ios_;
    ip::tcp::endpoint       ep_;
    ip::tcp::acceptor       acc_;
    ip::tcp::socket         socket_;
    std::mutex              mutex_socket_;

    std::string             ip_address_;
    short                   port_;
public:
    Server(io_service& ios, const std::string& ip_address, short port);
    ~Server();
    void ClientAccept();
    void ReadDataFromClient();
    void SendDataToClient();
    void StartThreads();

};

namespace util_server
{
    std::pair<std::string, short> CreateIpAndPort()
    {
        try
        {
            short port;
            std::string server_ip_address;

            std::cout << "IP: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, server_ip_address);
            if (server_ip_address == "localhost"){
                server_ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
            }

            std::cout << "Port: ";
            std::cin >> port;
            std::cin.ignore();
            return std::make_pair(server_ip_address, port);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error create_ip_and_port(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

    }

}
```

**Server.cpp**

```
#include "../headers/Server.h"


Server::Server(io_service& ios, const std::string& ip_address = "127.0.0.1", short port = 8080) :
    ip_address_             (ip_address),
    port_                   (port),
    ep_                     (ip::address::from_string(ip_address), port),
    ios_                    (ios),
    socket_                 (ios_),
    acc_                    (ios_, ep_)
{
    std::cout << "========================Server started!========================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Server IP: " << ip_address_<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "Server Port: " << port_ << std::endl;
}

Server::~Server() { ios_.stop(); }

void Server::ClientAccept() {
    acc_.async_accept(socket_, [self = shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "========Client connected========!" << std::endl;
            self->StartThreads();
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error accepting client: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        }
        });
    ios_.run();
}

void Server::ReadDataFromClient() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_socket_);
            std::shared_ptr<std::string> response = std::make_shared<std::string>();
            std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::streambuf> buffer = std::make_shared<boost::asio::streambuf>();
            async_read_until(socket_, *buffer, "\n",
                [self = shared_from_this(), response, buffer](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                    if (!error) {
                        std::istream is(buffer.get());
                        std::getline(is, *response);
                        std::cout << "Client message: " << *response << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "Error during async read: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error from ReadDataFromClient(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Server::SendDataToClient() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_socket_);
            std::shared_ptr<std::string> message = std::make_shared<std::string>();
            if (!std::getline(std::cin, *message)) {
                std::cerr << "Error reading input. Exiting..." << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*message), [self = shared_from_this(), message](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                if (!error) {
                    std::cout << "Message sent to server: " << *message << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "Error sending message: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                }
                });
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error from SendDataToClient(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Server::StartThreads() {
    auto thread_read = std::thread([self = shared_from_this()]() {
        self->ReadDataFromClient();
        });
    auto thread_send = std::thread([self = shared_from_this()]() {
        self->SendDataToClient();
        });

    thread_read.join();
    thread_send.join();

    ios_.run();
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    try {
        io_service service;
        auto pair = util_server::CreateIpAndPort();
        std::shared_ptr<Server> server = std::make_shared<Server>(service, pair.first, pair.second);
        server->ClientAccept();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error from main(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Ну и клиент**
client.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <locale>
#include <thread>

#include "utility.hpp"


#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601

#endif

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct Client {

    explicit Client(asio::io_service& ios, const std::string& ip_address, short port);
    void ConnectToServer();
    void ReadDataFromServer(tcp::socket& sock) const;
    void SendDataToServer(tcp::socket& sock) const;
    void StartThreads();
private:
    std::string             ip_address_;
    short                   port_;
    asio::io_service&       ios_;
    tcp::socket             socket_{ios_};
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep_;

    
};  


namespace util_client 
{
    std::pair<std::string, short> CreateIpAndPort()
    {
        try
        {
            short port;
            std::string server_ip_address;

            std::cout << "IP: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, server_ip_address);
            if (server_ip_address == "localhost"){
                server_ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
            }

            std::cout << "Port: ";
            std::cin >> port;
            std::cin.ignore();
            return std::make_pair(server_ip_address, port);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error create_ip_and_port(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

    }

}
```

**Client.cpp**

```
#include "../headers/Client.h"


Client::Client(asio::io_service& ios, const std::string& ip_address, short port) :
    ip_address_         (std::move(ip_address)),
    port_               (std::move(port)),
    ep_                 (asio::ip::address::from_string(ip_address_), port_),
    ios_                (ios)
    
{}

void Client::ConnectToServer() {
     socket_.connect(ep_);
     std::cout << "Connected\n";
}

void Client::ReadDataFromServer(tcp::socket& sock) const {
    try {
        while (true){
            std::string response;
            asio::streambuf buffer;
            asio::read_until(sock, buffer, "\n");
            std::istream is(&buffer);
            std::getline(is, response); 
            std::cout << "Server: " << response << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error in ReadDataFromServer(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }   
}

void Client::SendDataToServer(tcp::socket& sock) const {
    while (true) {
        std::string message;
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, message)) {
            std::cerr << "Error reading input. Exiting..." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else if (message == "Exit server") {
            std::cout << "-------Your exit!-------\n";
            ios_.stop();
            break;
        }

        asio::write(sock, asio::buffer(message), [this, &sock, message](const error_code& er, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
            if (!er) {
                std::cout << "Send message to server: " << message << std::endl;
                return bytes_transferred;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Error sending message" << std::endl;
            }
        });
    }
}

void Client::StartThreads() {
    auto thread_read = std::thread([this]() {
        this->ReadDataFromServer(socket_);
        });

    auto thread_write = std::thread([this]() {
        this->SendDataToServer(socket_);
        });

    thread_read.join();
    thread_write.join();

    ios_.run();
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    try {
        asio::io_service io_service;
        auto pair = util_client::CreateIpAndPort();
        Client client(io_service, pair.first, pair.second);
        client.ConnectToServer();
        client.StartThreads();     
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В вашем коде очень много проблем. Начать надо с понимания, зачем тут потоки на чтение/запись, если используются асинхронные операции. Потом еще все усугубляется блокировкой на мьютексе и бесконечными циклами добавления _запланированных_ операций чтения/записи. Улучшить код можно следующим образом: удалить его полностью, взять с официального сайта самые простые примеры клиента-сервера сначала в синхронном варианте, потом асинхронном, и на основе этих примеров можно делать свои попытки модификации.